# Using NextAuth to only hide a partial of the page like a reactions/comment form (question)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

Not sure If someone can give me an answer here. It's more like a best practice/logic question. I am working on my Next.js project using Sanity.io as a headless CMS. Now, I have created this reactions/comments form with `react-hook-forms` and I would like to prevent bots to post comments. But also to prevent people from posting rude comments. I do have **approval** logic/mode built-in just in case.

I am wrapping the **HOC** component which contains the form itself and the comments with the check with `session` to see if a user is logged in.

Will this stop bots? Or is this overkill to use for the form only? Or is there any kind of suggestion on what works with `react-hook-forms` to stop bots? Trying to roll my way in to become a Fullstack developer so that's why I am asking for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but, I worked with this social media platform (that is almost dead now because of bots), one thing I can say, most of those "bots" are actually humans or humans creating scripts to figureout your workaround, its a never ending battle. Goodluck

Comment: @IamL Good to know thank you that's an answer anyways. You can like protect it somehow a little bit but protecting it like 100% is not possible I am aware of that.

Comment: yea we even resorted on machine learning to evaluate each posts, but the bots figured out how to blend in with the crowd. What I suggest in the future is a shadowban system. Do not let the bot know that he is banned/blocked. if you've recognized a bot, only let him and the other bots see that post/comment. this would make him think that he's breaching your logic.

Comment: @IamL That's crazy machine learning and still bots are coming in. Thanks I will not worry too many bots will be always on the internet. I will use reCAPTCHA that's good enough.

Comment: yeah reCAPTHCA really helps for the automated ones!